# How to retrive data from DB to achieve the suggested layout?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am building a website from ASP.NET.
There is a page user can select the country.
Here is the screenshot

[image]

I am storing countries in a mysql table. But in this page I used hyperlinks like this

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<b><font size=3 color=green>A</font></b>"></asp:Literal><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/Categories.aspx?con=1&cou=1"    runat="server">Algeria</asp:HyperLink><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2"  NavigateUrl="~/Categories.aspx?con=1&cou=2" runat="server">Angola</asp:HyperLink><br />
```

So to achieve this layout I used above method. Instead of above method cant I load directly them from table and generate the above layout?. I tried to use tree view control. But that control is not going to give above format. I need that column layout. If you are suggesting me that use a gridview or some table control Please give me some example. I dont have any idea how to achieve that.

Remember I want to separate each name from green colour letter eg: "A" which is saying that names are begin with that particular letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `Repeater` controls one within another. One to display the Alphabet and the other to display the countries based on the first character.

Will give you and example in a moment (being cooked :-))

Ok, I just used a DataList and Repeater just to have a multiple columns with ease. You could do the same with Repeaters with some effort.

First have your markup as below

```
<asp:DataList ID="Categories" runat="server" ItemStyle-Width="150" RepeatColumns="4" 
        onitemdatabound="Categories_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlCategory" NavigateUrl="#" runat="server" ForeColor="#0099CC"><%# Container.DataItem %></asp:HyperLink><br />        
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptCountries" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlCountry" NavigateUrl="~/Categories.aspx?con=1&cou=1" runat="server"><%# Eval("Name") %></asp:HyperLink><br /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Then the code behind

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CountryDisplay;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a property to hold all your countries retrieved from the database
        /// I assume you have you'll have one row for each country
        /// </summary>
        public CountryCollection AllCountries
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["AllCountries"] != null)
                {
                    return (CountryCollection)ViewState["AllCountries"];
                }
                return new CountryCollection();
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["AllCountries"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetAllCountriesFromDatabase();

                char[] alphabet = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'S' }; // Get this from DB, I'm just mocking for illustration purpose.

                Categories.DataSource = alphabet;
                Categories.DataBind();                
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all Countries from database.
        /// </summary>
        private void GetAllCountriesFromDatabase()
        {
            AllCountries = new CountryCollection();
            /* At this point you should know how to retrieve your data from DB and fill the AllCountries collection
             E.g.

             AllCountries = DalService.GetAllCountriesFromDatabase(); // DalService could be your Data Access layer and GetAllCountriesFromDatabase() is one of it's methods

             I'll be creating some dummy logic to fill the collection for demo purpose from this point onwards

             */

            // Add countries to the collection
            Country country = new Country("America");
            country.ID = 1;
            AllCountries.Add(country);

            country = new Country("Australia");
            country.ID = 2;
            AllCountries.Add(country);

            country = new Country("Sri Lanka");
            country.ID = 3;
            AllCountries.Add(country);

            country = new Country("India");
            country.ID = 4;
            AllCountries.Add(country);

            country = new Country("Canada");
            country.ID = 5;
            AllCountries.Add(country);
        }

        protected void Categories_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
             e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                // Retrieve the hlCategory control in the current DataListItem.
                char cCategory = (char)e.Item.DataItem;
                Repeater rptCountries = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptCountries");

                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(cCategory) && rptCountries != null)
                {
                    rptCountries.DataSource = AllCountries.FindAll(a => a.Name.StartsWith(cCategory.ToString()));
                    rptCountries.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And some model classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CountryDisplay
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CountryCollection : List<Country> { }

    [Serializable]
    public class Country
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Country(string name)
        {
            this.ID = 0;
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helped!

Accept and vote the answer if it helped.

Comment: have a look at the updated answer. Add the logic the retrieve the data from database. I just mocked the data for illustration.